# Sentence starting with a prepositional phrase

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

This is from a TOEFL practice book:

Of all the lawsuits in the world, _____ in US courts.

A. Filed 95 percent of them

B. 95 percent of them are filed

C. That filed are 95 percent of them

D. Which of them 95 percent are filed

I don't have the answer key, but I see that the best answer is B.(I may be wrong)

However, I feel that all of the four are wrong.

Shouldn't we say "95 percent are filed" ?

Why to repeat "of them" when it had been already mentioned in the adverbial?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not necessary to refer back with _of them_, but there is nothing wrong with doing so.

Comment: A, C, and D are completely wrong.  B might be considered bad style, and would be less redundant without "of them", but it's still correct.

Comment: You're right, it isn't necessary and "why repeat or use more words" is a good style principle.   But only one of the choices can be correct grammar.